# youtube-dl specify output from python script?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm following the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) on using `youtube-dl` from a python script.

But I can't seem to get the output option, specifying the folder I want the download to go into to work:

```
ydl_opts = {'output':'video'}                                                                                                                           
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:                                                                                                         
  ydl.download([url])
```

I've also tried replacing `output` with `o` and `-o`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`outtmpl` (not `output`) is a *template* for the video file name, not a directory. An output template value of `'video'` instructs youtube-dl to write the video a file literally called video. Try something like

```
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': '/home/philip/my/videos/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',
}
```

If you want to know the name of further options, have a look at [the list of options](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L129-L310). For more information on the output template, refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template).